# Fancybox in loop for youtube videos

Tags: wordpress, loops, youtube, fancybox

This has been driving me crazy for the past few days, so I figured I would ask the question on here, there were similar posts... but none of them solved the issue. Thanks in advance for your help!

Here is what I am doing:

I have a wordpress page template that pulls a certain type of post, these posts have a custom field with a youtube embed url in it. When the page displays, I want the user to be able to click on the thumbnails to bring up the fancybox with the video in it.

Here is the problem:

The first link that displays in the loop works great... but the others do not (they go to a full screen video). I think it has to do with the id's all being the same. If this is the case, I am not sure how to make this happen. Any ideas on how to change the code or alternatives that I might want to try?

Here is the code:

```
$("#video").click(function() {
    $.fancybox({
            'padding'       : 0,
            'autoScale'     : false,
            'transitionIn'  : 'none',
            'transitionOut' : 'none',
            'title'         : this.title,
            'width'     : 680,
            'height'        : 495,
            'href'          : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
            'type'          : 'swf',
            'swf'           : {
                 'wmode'        : 'transparent',
                'allowfullscreen'   : 'true'
            }
        });


    return false;
});
```

And also:

```
 <a id="video" title="<?php the_title();?>" href="<?php echo $lightbox;?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'portfolio-post-thumbnail-xl' ); ?></a>
```

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: 1) you are using the manual method so you cannot have a gallery. 2). you are using (most likely) the same ID for more than one element... IDs should be unique within the same document, use classes instead.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I have tried changing "id" to "class" and all of the links open full screen... not in fancybox (before at least the first one worked). Is there an easy way to make the id's different for each link displayed? What would you recommend if class's were not an option?